# Merge two rows into one

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

When i run the below written procedure, the returned result set which i get is like

[image: My Result Set]

[image: Result Set 2]
But Actually according to the scenario, what i want is that I want a single record against the @ContractId parameter. So, I want to merge the rows which my result set returns.

PS: This image shows only few columns, there also exists some other columns which have different values.

This is My Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Tbl_Contract_SearchOne]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ContractID int
AS
BEGIN

    select  
    tbl_Contract.ContractID,
    KeyWinCountNumber, 
    ItemName,
    BrandName,
    CountName,
    SellerName,
    BuyerName,
    ContractNumber,
    ContractDate,
    CountryFromName,
    CountryToName,
    TotalQty,
    Vans,
    UnitPrice,
    Amount
    from tbl_Contract

    inner join tbl_CountDetail
    on
    tbl_CountDetail.ContractID = Tbl_Contract.ContractID
    inner join tbl_Count tcount
    on
    tcount.CountID = tbl_CountDetail.CountID
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Item
    on Tbl_Contract.ItemID = Tbl_Item.ItemID 
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Brand
    on Tbl_Contract.BrandID = Tbl_Brand.BrandID
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Seller
    on Tbl_Contract.SellerID = Tbl_Seller.SellerID
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Buyer 
    on Tbl_Contract.BuyerID = Tbl_Buyer.BuyerID
    INNER JOIN Tbl_CountryFrom
    ON Tbl_Contract.CountryFromID=Tbl_CountryFrom.CountryFromID
    INNER JOIN Tbl_CountryTo 
    ON Tbl_Contract.CountryToID = Tbl_CountryTo.CountryToID
    inner join tbl_CostUnit
    on Tbl_Contract.CostUnitID = tbl_CostUnit.CostUnitID    
    where Tbl_Contract.ContractID = 1
    and Tbl_Contract.IsDeleted = 0 and tbl_CountDetail.IsDeleted = 0
END
```

Comment: This question confuses me. Do you want to select the merge of these two rows? Do you want to update the various tables with these rows producing the output? Its a little confusing

Comment: I actually want to merge these two rows.

Comment: But how do you want to merge them? The only field that differs is CountName which is a string not an integer. How do you want to aggregate it? What do you want as output?

Comment: actually here the only field that differs is CountName but there are 4 more fields that differs. Amount, UnitPrice , Quantity etc.

Comment: Okay so you need to aggregate those fields (sum,average etc.) depending on whta kind of aggregation you need use it. If you need an example tell me

Comment: @AbidAli Can you edit your post and show the desired result that you want from your query?

Comment: ok wait. i`l edit the post

Comment: Please mention if still correctly explained or not.

Comment: @AbidAli can you show the actual data result you want from the query?  It is not clear how you are explaining it.

Comment: @AbidAli It is still not clear what you expect as the result from the query. You have multiple values for CountName, TotalQty, UnitPrice and Amount. Which one do you want to return?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the CountName field (the only value that differs between the two) but in theory you could just put it through an aggregation using `GROUP BY` (If you excluded CountName) or if you wanted to include CountName then maybe `PIVOT` would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under aggregation, quite often aggregation means doing an operation (sum, average, standard deviation) on th rows you want to compress into a single row. For example, if your data consisted off number of cookie sales per person per day:

```
day    person    sales
======================
1      Bob       5
1      Jane      8
2      Bob       2
2      Jane      10
```

And you wanted to see over *all* days what the total sales per person is, you would select `person` and the `sum(sales)` grouping by the person

```
select  
   person
   sum(sales)
from salesData
group by person
```

Your case is somewhat less standard, in that you are trying to aggregate a filed which is character-based, or alphanumeric. This is fine, sort of, in that there are some aggregations which will work with a character-field. `MIN` will still work, as wil `MAX` - returning the first and last field respectively.

ie, doing a `min` over the set `a`,`b`,`c` will return `a` as it is first (Minimum ordered by string ordering rules). You seem to have some other numeric fields (`Amount`,`UnitPrice`,`TotalQty`) - these you can pick the correct aggregation for - I suspect `SUM` is most likely

So you could do this:

```
select  
    tbl_Contract.ContractID,
    KeyWinCountNumber, 
    ItemName,
    BrandName,
    MIN(CountName) as FirstCountName,
    SellerName,
    BuyerName,
    ContractNumber,
    ContractDate,
    CountryFromName,
    CountryToName,
    SUM(TotalQty) AS SumTotalQuantity,
    Vans,
    SUM(UnitPrice) as TotalUnitPrice,
    SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
    from tbl_Contract
      [...snip...]
    group by  tbl_Contract.ContractID,
    KeyWinCountNumber, 
    ItemName,
    BrandName,
    SellerName,
    BuyerName,
    ContractNumber,
    ContractDate,
    CountryFromName,
    CountryToName,
    Vans
```

This will now return 1 row, where `FirstCountName` has the value  `Count1 502` as this is the first (min) value from the aggregated fields.